# Loops breaks before it ended

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, console, break

This loop breaks on the first time that it execute. Why.

```
<script>

for ( var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++ ) {

    console.log(i);

    if ( i = 5 ) {
        console.log (i);
        break;
    } 

}

</script>
```

output :
0
5

I'm expecting to :
0
1
2
3
4

Comment: i = 5 is an assignment, i == 5 is a comparison in JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a double/triple comparison operator in the IF statement `==` or `===`

```
<script>
    for ( var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++ ) {

        console.log(i);

        if ( i == 5 ) {
            console.log (i);
            break;
        } 

    }
</script>
```

Also, this will output `0 1 2 3 4 5 5`. If you want the output to be `0 1 2 3 4`, you should use the following code in place of the current `IF` statement.

```
if ( i == 4 ) {
    break;
}
```

Comment: Opps ! Thanks Man ! Great Detailed Answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `===` instead of `=` in the if statement

```
<script>

for ( var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++ ) {

    console.log(i);

    if ( i === 5 ) {
        console.log (i);
        break;
    } 

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The if evaluation is incorrect. Change it to...

```
if ( i == 5 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  i == 5 instead of i = 5 (assignment).